# Почему при клике на кнопки всегда 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу передавать id той кнопки, на которую нажали, но всегда передает 1, что не так? Кнопки генерируются динамически, поэтому обращаюсь через body.

```js
$(function () {
$("body").on('click', '.btn_add', function () {
    var cch = $(".btn_add").attr("id");
    console.log(cch);
    $("#inf").text(cch);
    var inf = $("#inf").attr("chainid", cch);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="inf"></span>
<button id="1" class="btn_add">s1</button>
<button id="2" class="btn_add">s2</button>
<button id="3" class="btn_add">s3</button>
```

Comment: Так а нафиг селектируете по классу в обработчике? Берите this

Comment: @yolosora если использую this, то в консоли: this.attr is not a function

Comment: А что Вы хотели? Находит все кнопки, берёт у первого `id`. Нужен `id` нажатой - используйте `$(this).attr('id');`.

Comment: `this` - это нативный объект (достаточно странное решение в кастомных обработчиках, но что есть...), нужно обернуть его в хуквери-обёртку.

Comment: @Other хах, видимо я не правильно прописывал this, спасибо, ошибку понял

Comment: `var cch = this.id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В третьей строке нужно использовать `$(this).attr("id");`

```js
$(function () {
$("body").on('click', '.btn_add', function () {
    var cch = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(cch);
    $("#inf").text(cch);
    var inf = $("#inf").attr("chainid", cch);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="inf"></span>
<button id="1" class="btn_add">s1</button>
<button id="2" class="btn_add">s2</button>
<button id="3" class="btn_add">s3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не правильно использовал this, так верно $(this).attr('id'); Всем спасибо!